# Integrate CKfinder in CKEditor

Tags: php

i have tried using this http://dwij.co.in/ckeditor-ckfinder-integration-using-php/ for integrating CKfinder with CKeditor but didnt work.

Its showing me error. "The file browser is disabled for security reasons. Please contact your system administrator and check the CKFinder configuration file". (Is this warrning is because i just download the trial version?)

Here is my config file.

```
<?php

function CheckAuthentication()
{

    return false;
}
$config['LicenseName'] = '';
$config['LicenseKey'] = '';

$baseUrl = 'http://localhost/test/uploads';

$baseDir = resolveUrl($baseUrl);

$config['Thumbnails'] = Array(
        'url' => $baseUrl . '_thumbs',
        'directory' => $baseDir . '_thumbs',
        'enabled' => true,
        'directAccess' => false,
        'maxWidth' => 100,
        'maxHeight' => 100,
        'bmpSupported' => false,
        'quality' => 80);

$config['Images'] = Array(
        'maxWidth' => 1600,
        'maxHeight' => 1200,
        'quality' => 80);

$config['RoleSessionVar'] = 'CKFinder_UserRole';

$config['AccessControl'][] = Array(
        'role' => '*',
        'resourceType' => '*',
        'folder' => '/',

        'folderView' => true,
        'folderCreate' => true,
        'folderRename' => true,
        'folderDelete' => true,

        'fileView' => true,
        'fileUpload' => true,
        'fileRename' => true,
        'fileDelete' => true);

$config['DefaultResourceTypes'] = '';

$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
        'name' => 'Files',              // Single quotes not allowed
        'url' => $baseUrl . 'files',
        'directory' => $baseDir . 'files',
        'maxSize' => 0,
        'allowedExtensions' => '7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip',
        'deniedExtensions' => '');

$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
        'name' => 'Images',
        'url' => $baseUrl . 'images',
        'directory' => $baseDir . 'images',
        'maxSize' => 0,
        'allowedExtensions' => 'bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png',
        'deniedExtensions' => '');

$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
        'name' => 'Flash',
        'url' => $baseUrl . 'flash',
        'directory' => $baseDir . 'flash',
        'maxSize' => 0,
        'allowedExtensions' => 'swf,flv',
        'deniedExtensions' => '');

$config['CheckDoubleExtension'] = true;

$config['DisallowUnsafeCharacters'] = false;

$config['FilesystemEncoding'] = 'UTF-8';

$config['SecureImageUploads'] = false;

$config['CheckSizeAfterScaling'] = true;

$config['HtmlExtensions'] = array('html', 'htm', 'xml', 'js');

$config['HideFolders'] = Array(".*", "CVS");

$config['HideFiles'] = Array(".*");

$config['ChmodFiles'] = 0777 ;

$config['ChmodFolders'] = 0777 ;

$config['ForceAscii'] = false;

$config['XSendfile'] = false;


include_once "plugins/imageresize/plugin.php";
include_once "plugins/fileeditor/plugin.php";
include_once "plugins/zip/plugin.php";

$config['plugin_imageresize']['smallThumb'] = '90x90';
$config['plugin_imageresize']['mediumThumb'] = '120x120';
$config['plugin_imageresize']['largeThumb'] = '180x180';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
function CheckAuthentication()
{

    return false;
}
```

By default `CheckAuthentication()` it is disabled for security reason, because it would allow anyone to upload files to your server.

For testing purposes you can return `true` but the point is that you implement some logic to only authorize autenticated user.

```
function CheckAuthentication()
{
    //put some logic here

    return isset($_SESSION['IsAuthorized']) && $_SESSION['IsAuthorized'];
}
```

Comment: What is the limitation in Demo version?

Answer (score 0):

**This is only for PHP User**

To enable CKFinder you have to just open config.php file in CKFinder folder

then search for the below code...

```
function CheckAuthentication()
{
    return false;
}
$config['LicenseName'] = '';
$config['LicenseKey'] = '';
```

Now Replace **false to true**

and put **LicenseName** and **LicenseKey**